# Smooth transition between classes, colours | .classList.toggle, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, toggle

As a beginner in JS, I am practicing a very simple operation: switching between dark and light themes.

Everything works well, but I want to have a smooth transition between classes, but I don’t know how to do it.

*To be exact, I want a smooth transition between **colours**.*

Please, help =)

Here is my js code:

```
let themer = document.querySelector('.page');

let themeButton = document.querySelector('.theme-button');

themeButton.onclick = function () {
  themer.classList.toggle('light-theme');
  themer.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transition rule where property is changing. e.g.:

```
transition: background-color 2s ease;
```